# Sending Image through TCP

Tags: c#, tcp

im trying to send an image through tcp, It works about 50% of the time, the other 50% is just giving me a black image and if i send 2 in the space of like 3 seconds it crashes. does anyone know why? and how i can fix this

Client:

```
                    while ((i = stream.Read(datalength, 0, 4)) != 0)
                {

                    byte[] data = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength, 0)];
                    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Image Screenshot = byteArrayToImage(data);
                            pictureBox1.Image = Screenshot;
                        }
                        catch { }
                    });
                }
```

This is the function which converts the byte array to image

```
        public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
```

Server:

```
        Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
                byte[] data = imageToByteArray(Image);
                stream = client.GetStream();
                int length = data.Length;
                byte[] datalength = new byte[4];
                datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
                stream.Write(datalength, 0, 4);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

This is the function that converts the image to byte array

```
        public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that you read the entire "packet". It is not certain that you receive everything just because you request it. The `Read()` method will return how many bytes have been read, store that and loop until you've received the right amount of bytes.

Replace your current `Read()` with this:

```
int bytesReceived = 0;
while(bytesReceived < data.Length)
{
    bytesReceived += stream.Read(data, bytesReceived, data.Length - bytesReceived);
}
```

This will read until your whole image has been received.

**EDIT:** Fixed a problem in code, thanks to [Ivan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36367174/3740093).

Comment: do you mean just replace "stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);" with your code? or the "while ((i = stream.Read(datalength, 0, 4)) != 0)"? thanks for helping

Comment: @RachelDockter : Replace `stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);` yes. The code will keep requesting as many bytes as it's missing, so if you've for example received everything but one byte, it will request only one byte.

Comment: @RachelDockter : If it works, please mark this as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on the left of the post.

Comment: oh wow its litrally perfect. i can click it really fast, it will sometimes say "error loading image" which was my try catch but it doesnt show a black screen or crash the server which is amazing. thank you alot :)

Comment: @RachelDockter : You're welcome! But you should probably log the error from the `catch`, it can help you identify _why_ you cannot load the image. --- I also have to say that you've made a clean and simple implementation of length-prefixing. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading 1000 bytes when you should be reading four. You're reading and throwing away a large part of the image following the length word.

You're also apparently ignoring the result of `read()`, and assuming that it fills the buffer.

Comment: i noticed that after i posted the question, i ll edit it. its a little better i guess but some of them still come back black. it seems like when i get a black screenshot, everyone after that one will be black until i restart the program

Comment: See edit. Once you get out of sync you will stay out of sync.

Comment: would u be able to explain abit more on ignoring the result of read() please? im havnt been programming for long and networking isnt my strong point

Comment: i can see the read() is reading the data and its size etc but im not sure how i would use that in my code

Comment: Most read() methods block until at least one byte is available, then transfer whatever bytes are available without blocking again, and return the count. You need to write a read loop that advances the offset and decrements the length until you've read all the data you're expecting (as per the length word). Or find a read method that does that for you.

Comment: that sounds complicated, would you know of any examples? i wouldnt even know what to search for

Comment: There are hundreds of examples here. I've posted hundreds myself.