# Sending Byte[] (TreeView) over TCP C#

Tags: c#, winforms, serialization, tcp, treeview

this may sound abit complex but i have a TreeView on a computer. I then convert it to a byte array, send it through TCP, convert the byte array back into a tree view and then view it again. For some reason its very buggy, the exact same treeview might work one time, then not for the next 10 times. It seems to work alot more if the TreeView is smaller. I know for a fact the error is from sending it through tcp because ive made a program which just converts it to byte array and back which works 100% of the time. Here is the code:

```
byte[] data = SerilizeQueryFilters(TreeFiles); //Convert to byte[] function, 100% works fine.

stream = client.GetStream();
int length = data.Length;
byte[] datalength = new byte[4];
datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);
stream.Write(datalength, 0, 4);
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //Sends the byte[]
```

So thats the code from the server which sends it to the clients. at this point im not sure if im sending it wrong so its receiving it wrong or visa versa.

Code to receive the byte array:

```
stream = client.GetStream();
new Thread(() =>
{
    try
    {
        while ((i = stream.Read(datalength, 0, 4)) != 0)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength, 0)];
            int bytesReceived = 0;

            while (bytesReceived < data.Length)
            {
                bytesReceived += stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length - bytesReceived);
            }
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    if (CBCommand.SelectedItem.ToString() == "View Files")
                    {
                        DeSerilizeQueryFilters(data, TVFiles); //Convert the byte[] back into the tree view and view it
                        WriteToLog("Finished");
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            });
        }
    }
    catch { }
}).Start();
```

Bare in mind i have other functions which i left out for receiving images, and strings which use the exact same code and they work fine so im guessing its because its a treeView. Converting the byte[] back into the treeView function works 100% but as thats where its messing up (because the byte[] is corrupted or didnt send properly) ill include the code for that below

```
private void DeSerilizeQueryFilters(byte[] items, TreeView Treeview)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    List<TreeNode> _list = new List<TreeNode>();
    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ms.Write(items, 0, items.Length);
            ms.Position = 0;
            _list = bf.Deserialize(ms) as List<TreeNode>;
            Treeview.Nodes.AddRange(_list.ToArray());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { WriteToLog("Error displaying files"); Console.WriteLine(ex); }
}
```

So when it fails it will give me the message error displaying files and write the exception which ill include below just in case:

System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 6D-73-2E-54-72-65-65-4E-6F-64-65-02-00-00-00-1D-53 ...
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerializationHeaderRecord.Read(__BinaryParser input)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadSerializationHeaderRecord()
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)

Sorry about the long post, thanks for reading, any ideas are appriciated

Comment: When you say TreeView, do you mean a hierarchy of objects, or some sort of UI control?

Comment: The windows form TreeView which displays a hierarchy of objects

Comment: If you want to transfer the structure over a network connection I would recommend creating DTOs. Are you using WCF?

Comment: im just using windows forms, im a beginner at programming and for this i was just looking to only use windows forms as all the other features transfer over tcp in the same way. i was hoping there was just a small fix to this as its only the treeview thats not working where images/ strings are

Comment: Are you using the TCP to send the TreeView between 2 processes on the same machine?

Comment: Not sure if that's the main problem, but this code `bytesReceived += stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length - bytesReceived);` has potential issue. Change it to `bytesReceived += stream.Read(data, bytesReceived, data.Length - bytesReceived);`

Comment: im using my pc which is the server and it converts and sends the treeview to my laptop which is the client which recieves and converts the treeview back if that makes sense.

Comment: ill give that a go ivan

Comment: im 99% sure that fixed it as its working flawlessly now. also sending an image would fail about 20% of the time and now it seems to be working 100% of the time. thankyou alot :)

Comment: I don't think using a TCP connection like this provides as reliable transmission as creating a WCF service. The server transmits the data but I'm not sure message delivery to the client process is guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reading loop has an issue:

```
while (bytesReceived < data.Length)
{
    bytesReceived += stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length - bytesReceived);
}
```

The second argument to the `Stream.Read` is a buffer offset. Since you are passing 0 (zero), every read call basically overrides the previous, thus ending up with an incorrect data. This also explains why it works with small data - because if it is read in one pass, everything is fine.

The correct way is to pass `bytesReceived` as offset:

```
while (bytesReceived < data.Length)
{
    bytesReceived += stream.Read(data, bytesReceived, data.Length - bytesReceived);
}
```

Comment: My fault, I missed that when I wrote this snippet for the OP. ;)

Comment: @VisualVincent Np, it happens :)